# How to kill used port of docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run one docker image and it is saying address already in use

```
 driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jovial_saha (c79c98cbcef6340cd7867571278f401c9cbea1fd7137a39fe5d7de1c454d4e6e): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9042: bind: address already in use.
```

However i have  deleted all containers and images and then even if i call to run my image  by

```
docker run -d -p 9042:9042 myimage . i get above error. what  should i do ?
```

Comment: Something on that macvhine is listening to port 9042.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand on Robert Moskal's answer, you'll need to kill whatever's already on that port:

- kill all the containers again
- if you're on Linux, kill the process running on your port with `fuser -k 9042/tcp`
- if above steps don't work, reboot your computer and try again.

Happy hunting!

Comment: my local port was blocked. i am new to docker  and seems  so much into that i missed\overlooked my local proccess running on same  port. thanks for quick help .

Comment: This just bit me as well :-(

Answer (score 4):

I used with `sudo`. it worked me.

```
sudo fuser -k 9042/tcp
```

I check port status:

```
$ netstat -pna | grep 9042
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using `fuser` on host didn't solve the issue.

Instead, install `psmisc` on docker and then use `fuser`.

```
$ apt-get install psmisc
$ fuser -k 9042/tcp
```

It worked for me.